# Upper bound on a series of integrals

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\{\omega_i\}_{i\ge 1}$ be a bounded sequence of positive numbers and consider the following series of nested integrals
$$
S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^{t} \cos(\omega_1t_1)\left(\int_0^{t_1} \cos(\omega_2t_2)\cdots \left(\int_0^{t_{n-1}} \cos(\omega_nt_n)\, \mathrm{d}t_n\right)\cdots\mathrm{d}t_2\right)  \mathrm{d}t_1
$$

If $\omega_i=\bar \omega$ for all $i$, then the above series converges to (see, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33442/series-of-nested-integrals?rq=1))
$$
 \exp\left({\int_0^t \cos(\bar \omega \tau )\, \mathrm{d}\tau}\right)-1,
$$
so that, in this special case, a simple upper bound to the series $S$ is given by
$$
S\le \exp\left({\frac{1}{\bar \omega}}\right)-1.
$$

> Now, let's go back to the general case of different $\omega_i$'s and define
>   $$\bar \omega:=\min_{i\ge 1} \omega_i.$$
>   Is it true that 
>   $$
> S\le \exp\left({\frac{1}{\bar \omega}}\right)-1 \ \ \ ?
> $$